# Google spreadsheet Custom Conditional Formatting Not Working

Tags: google-sheets

I want to to make an if statement that says if E2:E = 0 and D2:D > 0 then say Not Done. I tried going into custom conditional formatting and inserting this if statement :

IF(E2:E=0,IF(D2:D>0,"Not Done",""),"")       but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find the sum of values in E2:E and D2:D, you can do it like this. Instead of a nested IF statement, use and() to evaluate both conditions for true or false in one expression. It's a little simpler.

```
=IF(and(sum(E2:E)=0,sum(D2:D)>0),"Not Done","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional format doesn't *say* things, it changes the format of cells, font style and color or cell color.

If you want a cell to say "Not Done" go to an empty column like F, and put your formula in cell `F2`:

```
=IF(E2=0,IF(D2>0,"Not Done",""),"")
```

Then you can copy F2 to all the cells in column F.

If you want to format the cells that are not done, select the cells you want formatted, like `E2:D20`, and put a boolean expression (that returns true or false) in the custom formula:

```
=AND(E2:E=0,D2:D>0)
```

Then choose a different format from your regular one in the Formatting style of the Conditional format.